# Why the default value of spring transactional propagation is `REQUIRED` instead of `NESTED`

Tags: spring, transactions, propagation

I read the `Transactional` documentation and found that `NESTED` and `REQUIRED` behave very similarly, why is `propagation` default value `REQUIRED`.

```
@Service
class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Transactional
    public void a() {
        // ...
        try {
            b.b();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // not throw exception
        }
        // ...
    }
}

@Service
class B {
    @Transactional
    public void b() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Consider the above code. Even though I `catch` the `exception` thrown from `b`, `a` still rollback. If `b` uses `NESTED`, then it won't rollback. In this case, the code will look verbose. According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NESTED), we know that they behave similarly, so why?

> Execute within a nested transaction if a current transaction exists, behave like REQUIRED otherwise.

**UPDATE:**

If a throws an exception, I need them both to rollback.

Comment: They are different and not even supported by all database vendors where REQUIRED is supported by all of them. NESTED is more or less about committing chunks of data in a single transaction and use savepoints to keep track and only revert the last save point, while REQUIRED is all or nothing. Appears as if you actually wanted/needed `REQUIRES_NEW` (a fresh transaction) on method `b`.

Comment: I can't use `REQUIRES_NEW` because I need them both to rollback if `a` throws an exception. Does my understanding correct: `REQUIRED` supports all databases, but `NESTED` is not. If this is their difference, I'm really appreciate your answer.

Comment: If `NESTED` is supported or not depends on the fact if JDBC Savepoints are supported by a) the database JDBC driver, b) the technology in use, Hibernate for instance doesn't support it.